# Can I enable AHCI mode of the SATA controller when booting to Windows on a MacBook with Nvidia chipset?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sata

Is there a way to enable AHCI mode under Windows on a Macbook5,2 (white) on N-Force 730i chipset?
<sup>If you want to just say 'no', please put it in the comments instead. Thanks.</sup>

[Advanced Host Controller Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface) mode provides additional features of the [SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) standard and can be implemented in BIOS on some motherboards to improve performance.

Comment: I assume you are talking about running Windows with Boot Camp. Is that correct?

Comment: Helpful edit, @WheatWilliams. To the OP, why would you request that an answer be posted as a comment?

Comment: @Daniel An edit changed the content of my question drastically, so please reconsider your downvote.

Comment: @WheatWilliams I am NOT using an SSD, please do not edit my question.

Comment: @WheatWilliams [What is Boot Camp anyway?](http://refit.sourceforge.net/myths/)

Comment: @Kinokijuf, participants here edit questions to make them more understandable. Your initial question was short on details and context, and could not be easily understood by other readers. I'm sorry if I inferred things incorrectly. Nobody around here considers me "evil". So please explain, are you using Boot Camp to run Windows on a MacBook, or not? If not, how are you doing it? What do you need to accomplish with AHCI mode?

Comment: @WheatWilliams What you mean by Boot Camp.

Comment: I am running Windows without any sort of virtualisation/emulation software.

Comment: How did you go about installing Windows? People usually install Mac OS X and then use the Apple Boot Camp utility to partition the drive and start the Windows installation process. It also means that you are using the Apple hardware device drivers for Windows. That is pertinent to figuring out how to help you. So are you running Mac OS X and Windows in a dual-boot configuration on a partitioned hard drive, like we would expect, or do you mean that you are running Windows all by itself with no Mac OS X on the system? I've never heard of any one doing that.

Comment: @WheatWilliams Yes, I am running a dualboot configuration, bu that doesn’t matter.

Comment: kinoijuf - theres are hacks that rewrite the master boot record to enable AHCI under EFI (Grub2 I beleive) but not for the faint at heart.  Also the only documented sucesses I have found were on Intel chipsets, but I cannot see any reason for it not to work.

Comment: @StuWilson Under EFI AHCI is already enabled, because it is needed for OSX. I want to enable it under MBR, for Windows.

Comment: Kinokijuf - thats what the hack is for, to enable it under windows. http://reboot.pro/10362/

Comment: @StuWilson does this work on nvidia chipsets?

Comment: Kinokijuf, sorry I can't tell you. However I believe it should since the process is about adding a boot loader that overrides the Bootcamp loader and it's AHCI switch off configuration.  As long as the Nvidia chipset drivers are AHCI enabled, I think it's worth a try.  Obviously backup **everything first**